# Change gtk-2 scrollbar to something like overlay scrollbar (in appearance)

Tags: overlay-scrollbars, scrollbar, gtkrc, gtk-2

When there are scroll wheels on mice and scrollbar functions on thouchpads, a low contrast wide scrollbar doesn’t make sense. So I wanted to change gtk-2.0 scrollbar to something like overlay one – orange *narrow* slider with *white* background.

I couldn’t find anything about this topic here, so I decided to write something about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is in /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc – for example, for Ambiance theme. You can edit this file through Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

It contains anything about everything, so be careful.

If you don’t mind about the procedure, you can download [my file](http://ubuntuone.com/5PRrfj15mb71a2vGwvyV7U) and replace the gtkrc with it, by the command:

```
sudo cp "~/Downloads/gtkrc" /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

and whithin the quotation marks put your path for the downloaded file.

---

### The procedure

•   Under the block **style "default"** you can find some lines starting with *GtkScrollbar*. `GtkScrollbar::slider-width` is clear to define slider width, so put the value "**3**" for it.

•   To remove scrollbars steppers we add two more lines:

`GtkScrollbar::has-forward-stepper = 0`
`GtkScrollbar::has-backward-stepper = 0`

and change the `GtkRange::stepper-size` to "**1**".

•   Now, we go to change the colors! Under the block **style "scrollbar"**, put the same orange color for three **bg** colors:

`bg[NORMAL] = @selected_bg_color`
`bg[PRELIGHT] = @selected_bg_color`
`bg[ACTIVE] = @selected_bg_color`

Of course you can use different numbers on your choice. For example, if you want the slider to get darker when you hold it by mouse, use smaller values for ACTIVE mode.

•   At last, in *the same* block under the block **engine "murrine"**, I applied some modifications to make the slider look like overlay:

`roundness = 0`
`contrast = 0.0`
`trough_shades = {1.3, 1.2}`
`glowstyle = 3`

---

Here is the result (it will be a bit better now, because I’ve edited gtkrc after making these screenshots):

[image: Change gtk-2 scrollbar to something like overlay]